# cannot run function after ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i tried to make data security in ajax process by adding csrf_token token on the previous codeigniter when i first click the first and second `next` button to work properly, but then error `The action you have requested is not allowed.` here i use canvas to display pdf. how to handle it?

my ajax :

```
next = function() {
    var id_module= $('[name="id"]').val();    
    var token = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";

    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"user/home/update-slide/",
        data:{ id: id, "token": token},
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },  
        error: function (request, status, error){
            console.log(request.responseText);
         }          
    });     
    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 hm-gradient">
    <div id="pdf-main-container">
        <div id="pdf-contents">
            <canvas id="pdf-canvas" class="" width="790"></canvas>
            <div id="page-loader">Loading page ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>                          
</div>    

<button  onclick="return next();" class="btn btn-success">Next<span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the name of your posted token should not be "token", unless you changed the value in config/config.php:

```
// $config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';
```

So, maybe try this:

```
next = function() {
    var id_module= $('[name="id"]').val();

    // Get the current token name
    var token_name = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";

    // Get the actual token value
    var token = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";

    // Create the post data, which includes the token (with proper name)
    var postData = {'id':id};
    postData[token_name] = token;

    // POST
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"user/home/update-slide/",
        data:postData,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },  
        error: function (request, status, error){
            console.log(request.responseText);
         }          
    });     
    return false;
}
```

#### Update

So, what you need to do is put the token in a hidden HTML input to make this work:

```
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    id="csrf" 
    name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" 
    value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" />
```

By doing that, when you want to submit your form, you would get the name and value like this:

```
var postData = {'id':id};
var token_name = $('#csrf').attr('name');
var token = $('#csrf').val();
postData[token_name] = token;
```

And then in CodeIgniter you pass back a new token, so in your JavaScript success method update the token:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // Update token
    $('#csrf').val( data.token );
},
```

Which means in CodeIgniter you probably need something like this for the response:

```
echo json_encode([
    'token' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
]);
```

This is not tested, but very similar to how I do it.

Comment: thanks @Brian Gottier, yes i've changed the config in `$ config ['csrf_token_name'] = 'token';` and i tried with your script but its still the same problem, so when i click `next`  first run but second i click he error `action you asked not to be allowed`, i think error on ajax

Comment: You're going to want to look in the net/network panel of your browser's developer console for some clues. If nothing there, you'll probably need to do some debugging in PHP. Theoretically if you have the proper token name and value, and if the cookie is being set, then you wouldn't have the problem you are having.

Comment: I just found the problem, so when I click crsf not to reset so still to read the old token, do you know to reset its token when clicked next

Answer (score 0):

is'nt it that your base_url in the ajax must be enclosed with a php tag?

Comment: Irwan has a specific problem related to CodeIgniter’s CSRF tokens. It’s obvious, based on the error, that the request is being denied because CSRF is not satisfied. This has nothing to do with the concatenation of the URL.